# Bootstrapping gives me significance, without it not so much

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap, multiple-comparisons

For instance, in the table below, a GLM (ANOVA) Tukey posthoc bootstrapped 1000 times gives me a confidence interval like this. The columns are mean difference, bias, standard error, and the bounds of the CI.

[image]

However, without a bootstrap with a Tukey multiple comparison, I get this. The columns are mean difference, standard error, significance, and the CI as the last two columns.

[image]

Which one do I believe?

(I used SPSS to perform the analysis and bootstrap)

Comment: What groups do you compare exactly? (The figue only shows comparisons with A17s.) If you are only interested in comparisons wrt this reference, then maybe Dunnet's method would fit perfectly, maybe outperforming a pairwise Tukey approach where you are inerested only in part of the output.) Nice question.

Comment: @MichaelM I am just showing the A17S as an example. In reality, I would prefer to compare as many as possible. The problem with this experiment is that there are multiple controls (about 5 controls for one test subject). And the controls also have to be compared to each other. I had thought about Dunnet's, but Dunnet's only accepts one control group (If I am right) ?

Comment: Right, thanks for clarification. If all comparisons are equally important, then a method like Dunnet would really not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to verify the [assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_variance#Assumptions_of_ANOVA) of the ANOVA model. Look at the residuals. It depends on the amount of data that you have, if it is *enough*, then I would rely on the bootstrap.

Comment: The assumptions are all met (normally distributed and homogeneous variances). What would you classify as "enough" amount of data? The n number  (n=10) for each of the groups (A10S,A10T,A17S,A17T etc...) is enough biologically (per other publications in the field.)

Comment: Is there a standard way to do it in the field? If so then you should at least report those results. There is nothing wrong with reporting both. If you only report the bootstrapping results, then it may look like you are hunting for significance. 

At least showing that both methods do not yield the same results shows that there might be need for another way to model this or you might need more data to support this.

Comment: Thats the problem isn't it? If I do report both results, I won't be able to form a conclusion for the null hypothesis. Statistically what does make sense ?The usual method is t-testing/ANOVA with normal multiple comparisons (but in my field we practice disastrous statistics, so wouldnt rely on that) . I resorted to using confidence intervals (advice of supervisor), and I read up on the web that bootstrapping allows us to predict confidence intervals more accurately, I ended up doing that.

Comment: Well how does it make sense that the two methods yield different results? The methods are based on different principles. The multiple comparison method may become to conservative if you have too many groups and is a more naive way of doing this imo. The bootstrap is estimating the CIs directly from the data distribution and is more likely going to give you something that is closer to the truth. I assume you are familiar with [issues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem) in doing multiple comparisons.

Comment: If your field accepts the bootstrap, then I would motivate why you are using it and publish those results.

Comment: Many thanks. Yes I am familiar with the issues of multiple comparisons. Your answer has been most helpful. My field accepts bootstraps.. so shouldn't be an issue when publishing it.

Comment: Hope your manuscript gets accepted! :)

Comment: n=10 seems a little bit low to really verify how well the distributions are approximated by a normal distribution. That would be an argument for favoring the bootstrap result, which does not rely on normality.

Comment: @shane Thanks! It is n=10 per group, so a total of n=60. But it is a good point to be noted.

Comment: @shane: I do not quite agree. Bootstrap is a large sample method too. The smaller the sample size, the more cautious we need to be with bootstrap.

Comment: @MichaelM I see. Do you think a bootstrap is justified in this scenario then? (The tests for normality shapiro wilks and ks both strongly agree (on overall data (n=60) and per group (n=10*6 groups) that the data is normal).

Comment: What would you do if bootstrap gave less significant differences than the classic method? It would be ideal to see how the different types of bootstrap intervals (basic, percentile, t) would agree but I don't know if SPSS has these options?

Comment: @MichaelM the above is percentile based bootsrap. I also tried Bias Corrected Acceleration bootstrap (the only other bootstrap available in SPSS). Both agree with each other. Personally, I prefer the bootstrap data as anything resampled 1000 times will be more accurate ? Am I wrong in this?

Comment: It is definitively a good sign if both bootstrap methods lead to similar results. I would increase the number of bootstrap runs to the maximal feasible limit (e.g. wait for 10 minutes), then publish the accelerated bootstrap results with a comment that percentile bootstrap leads to similar results. Note that even running 10000000 bootstrap runs won't make bootstrap a reliable method in small sample settings.

Comment: @MichaelM I see. Any reason you prefer the BCa over percentile based bootstrap?